# Order by rollno text in LINQ c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a query in LINQ for getting detail of all students according to roll no. The roll no field is `string` type. But I need to order by roll no as a `int`.

```
var search = (from fs in Table1
               join fsroll in Table2 on fs.tempId equals fsroll.tempId2
               join ui in db.UserInfos on fsmuser.FormElementValue equals ui.UserInfoID.ToString()
               select new UserViewModel
               {
                   AvatarURL = ui.AvatarURL,
                   FirstName = ui.FirstName,
                   LastName = ui.LastName,
                   UserInfoID = ui.UserInfoID,
                   MobileNo = fsroll.FormElementValue,
                   loginStatus = ui.LoginStatus,
               }).OrderBy(a => a.FirstName);
```

Now I am ordering students by their name alphabetically. But I need to order them by `rollno`, which is text field.

So, how to convert that into `int` for ordering students in `rollno`.

Comment: [`int.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You could use `Convert.ToInt32(rollno)`. But if roll no is number in `string` format you don't need to convert it to `int`.

Comment: i tried both Convert.ToInt32(rollno)   and int.Parse both are not working

Comment: how do they not work?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.             my return type is as..... return View(await search.ToListAsync());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.OrderBy(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.rollno));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var search = (from fs in Table1
           join fsroll in Table2 on fs.tempId equals fsroll.tempId2
           join ui in db.UserInfos on fsmuser.FormElementValue equals ui.UserInfoID.ToString()
           select new UserViewModel
           {
               AvatarURL = ui.AvatarURL,
               FirstName = ui.FirstName,
               LastName = ui.LastName,
               UserInfoID = ui.UserInfoID,
               MobileNo = fsroll.FormElementValue,
               loginStatus = ui.LoginStatus,
               rollNumber=fsroll.RollNumber 
           }).OrderBy(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.rollNumber));
```

OR

```
var search = (from fs in Table1
           join fsroll in Table2 on fs.tempId equals fsroll.tempId2
           join ui in db.UserInfos on fsmuser.FormElementValue equals ui.UserInfoID.ToString()
           orderby Convert.ToInt32(fsroll.rollNumber)   
           select new UserViewModel
           {
               AvatarURL = ui.AvatarURL,
               FirstName = ui.FirstName,
               LastName = ui.LastName,
               UserInfoID = ui.UserInfoID,
               MobileNo = fsroll.FormElementValue,
               loginStatus = ui.LoginStatus
           });
```